# Number of satisfying assignments

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory

How many satisfying assignments does the following formula have?

(x1 ∨ x¯2 ∨ x¯3)(x1 ∨ x2)(x¯1 ∨ x¯2)

Comment: There are only $3$ variables. You can just enumerate all $2^3 = 8$ assignments and check if they satisfy the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 8 options:

T F F

T T F

T T T

F T T

F F T

F F F

T F T

F T F

When the first column is x1 the second is x2 and the third x3

Lets try each one:
(T or T or T)and(T or F)and(F or T)=T and T and T=T

(T or F or T)and(T or T)and(F or F)=F
And so on...

You can continue from here and you will get the right answer

Comment: T F F is listed twice...

Comment: You are right,fixed that!thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much!